# How can I display data from one page onto another page in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

So I am creating an expense tracking and budgeting app, and I have an idea that I want to implement. So I created a page (or app in Django) called **"Budgets"** and what I want to see when I select it is a table with columns **'Project Name'**, **'Budget (currency)'**, **'Expenses (currency)'**, **'Profit/Loss (currency)'**. Now I have added a button on top which says "Add Budgets" and when I click it a form appears which I only have to feed 'Project Name' and 'Budget' and **NOT** the other two.
I also have another page/app called **"Expenses"** which has every expense for the particular project. Now what I want is:

1. To transfer the sum of all the expenses from the **"Expenses"** page/app and display it under the column 'Expenses' in the Budgets page.
2. To make an automatic calculation of the profit/loss (i.e. Budget - Expenses) and have it display under the column 'Profit/Loss' in the Budgets page.

I know for some people the question might not be clear and maybe extra information or attachments may be required, please don't hesitate to ask. I have not provided any code because I am unsure of what might be needed in particular.